# How does one create and send TXs on L2 - Arbitrum and others?

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, layer-2, arbitrum, bridge

In ethers.js or web3.js

How does one create and send TXs on L2 - Arbitrum and others? Is the algorithm absolutely identical to the one on L1, or not?

How does one transfer ETH between L1 and L2?

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm should be the same because every L2 Ethereum chain works with the EVM (Ethereum VIrtual Machine). It is the algorithm every L2 ethereum chain uses

Comment: Ok. There's also the question of how move coins between L1 and L2, by ethers.js or web3.js

Comment: I don't know that I'm sorry I would help you